# awk with egrep filter unable to return null value with condition

Tags: awk, grep

I new in awk, my command as below. When there is no row return need print pass, else print fail. But when there is no value, the pass is unable to display

```
egrep -v "^\+" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '($1!="root" && $1!="sync" && $1!="shutdown" && $1!="halt" && $3<500 && $7!="/sbin/nologin") {print}' | awk '{if(NR==0||NR<=0||'null') print "pass"; else print "fail"}'
```

The result should return pass but there is noting print, please advice on this.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable, sample input and expected output so we're not guessing about what your input file contains or what you want output.

Answer (score 1):

consolidate all into one, for example

```
$ awk -F: '!/^+/ && $1!="root" && ... {f=1; exit} 
       END {print (f?"fail":"pass")}' /etc/passwd
```

perhaps better if you set the exit code

```
$ awk -F: '!/^+/ && $1!="root" && ... {exit 1}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: IMHO you shoud add a flag for not printing "pass"  if failed occur because:  *(from awk doc) An exit statement that is not part of a BEGIN or END rule stops the execution of any further automatic rules for the current record, skips reading any remaining input records, and executes the END rule if there is one*

Comment: Seems like a lot of negatives - I would hope there's a way to specify whatever condition the OP wants satisfied in a positive rather than multi-negative way.

Answer (score 1):

This MAY be what you're trying to do:

```
awk -F: '/^+/ || $1~/^(root|sync|shutdown|halt)$/ || $3>=500 || $7=="/sbin/nologin"{next} {f=1; exit} END{print (f ? "pass" : "fail")}'
```

Comment: like always, direct and efficient